# I wanna compress folders from one network drive to another network drive using 7zip over cmd, jenkins

Tags: compression, 7zip

I have folders on server 1, and i just want to compress files to another server.

So i tried with:

> 7z a "\server1\plugins\Arhiva_plugins_2018_01.7z
>   "\server2\jenkinstest*"

7zip compressed everything on \server1\pluigins\

Is it possible to compress folders on the third side with 7zip commands?

p.s. all command using on windows server, via cmd.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the third side' here? You're saying that 7z is ignoring a network share path? I've just tried it here and it works for me. You know that network shares have double-backslashes, i.e. \\server2\jenkinstest ?

Comment: i figure out at the and.. got some confusing, because i already used like robocopy commands :) thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figure out.

switch the places

> 7z a \server2\jenkinstest\Arhiva_plugins_2018_01.7z
>   \server1\plugins\